# How to write a text box control on C++/CX for Windows Metro Style application?

Tags: textbox, microsoft-metro, ui-automation, soft-keyboard, c++-cx

I need to write a text box control for Metro Style app. And I need that this text box can invokes a touch keyboard, when my app runs on tablet PC.

Microsoft advices me:

> If you are writing a custom text control (whether in Xaml or not) you will need to make sure it supports the UI Automation TextPattern and ValuePatterns and focus changed events

and

> You will need to provide an AutomationPeer which supports the ITextProvider and IValueProvider.

But I can't to figure out what actually I need to do. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have a text box control *without* the touch keyboard already?

Comment: Is your code in C++ or C#?  (The UI Automation interfaces are a bit different depending on the language.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a UI Automation Provider; in particular, you need to implement a server-side provider.  Start with the [UI Automation Provider Programmer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and pay particular attention to the [Document Content Provider Sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=241458), as it demonstrates how to implement TextPattern.  There are more samples as part of the [Windows 8 SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=226658), in the samples/ui/uiautomation directory. Also, there's a very quick introduction to server-side introductions [here](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0810112), written by one of the architects of UI Automation.